# Object is not getting mocked. Throwing Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, hbase, mockito

I am running my code with mockito framework. Framework is creating mocked object for One Implementation and not creating any mock object for other object due to that it is throwing null pointer exceptions. Here is my code and output:

```
package com.sohi;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Get;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTableInterface;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTablePool;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;

public class HbaseExample {

    private HTablePool pool;

    private static final String HTABLE_NAME = "table1";

    public String getValue(String rowKey, String columnFamily, String columnName) throws IOException {

        HTableInterface table = pool.getTable(HTABLE_NAME);

        Get get = new Get(Bytes.toBytes(rowKey)).addColumn(Bytes.toBytes(columnFamily), Bytes.toBytes(columnName));

        System.out.println("Is table Null  ? " + (table == null));

        Result result = table.get(get);

        System.out.println("is result null ? " + (result == null));

        byte [] val = result.value();



        return Bytes.toString(val);
    }

}
```

---

My Mockito Test class is :

---

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Get;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTablePool;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import com.sohi.HbaseExample;


@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class HbaseExampleTest {

    @Mock
    HTablePool pool;

    @Mock
    HTable hTable;

    @Mock
    Result result;


    @InjectMocks
    HbaseExample hbase = new HbaseExample();

    private static final String HTABLE_NAME = "table1";

    private static final String ROW_KEY = "k1";
    private static final String COLUMN_FAMILY = "col1";
    private static final String COLUMN_NAME = "c1";

    private static final String CELL_VALUE = "v1";

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        Get get1 = new Get(Bytes.toBytes(ROW_KEY)).addColumn(Bytes.toBytes(COLUMN_FAMILY), Bytes.toBytes(COLUMN_NAME));

        Mockito.when(pool.getTable(HTABLE_NAME)).thenReturn(hTable);
        Mockito.when(hTable.get(get1)).thenReturn(result);
        Mockito.when(result.value()).thenReturn(Bytes.toBytes(CELL_VALUE));

        String str = hbase.getValue(ROW_KEY, COLUMN_FAMILY, COLUMN_NAME);

        assertEquals(str, CELL_VALUE);

    }

}
```

Output is :

Is table Null  ? false
is result null ? true

And Also throwing null pointer exception near result.value().

only table object is getting mocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 Mockito.when(hTable.get(get1)).thenReturn(result);
```

This does not match your actual call, because your `get1` is not equal to the `Get` object that is actually passed. (It looks the same, but `Get` does not override `equals()` and so uses the default behaviour of treating any two different objects as being unequal.)

I suggest that you use a Captor to capture the `Get` object and add asserts to verify that the correct information is present. (I think this is a better way to write this sort of test anyway - it keeps all the assertions together, and leads to better error messages if you pass the wrong thing.)

Comment: I had same code in my other work space it was working. But In new work space I am getting this issue . I don't know what is going wrong

Comment: I bet it wasn't exactly the same. What you have will work for lots of objects which override `equals()`; but `Get` isn't one of them.

Comment: I got this. I used Get from two versions. I am getting this issue with older library . When I included which is having equals in Get then It worked. But I have to work with older library. If so then I can mock that object (because its not having equals method).           Any suggestion ?

Comment: Use a captor (see last paragraph in the answer, and http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/Captor.html). Or you could write your own custom argument matcher (http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/Matchers.html), but I think that's a lot messier.